# Set values of components of all Child views in Expandable List

Tags: android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I have an Expandable List that represents settings in my program. The group view has a TextView description with a Button that represents a reset. The child view has a TextView description with an EditText that represents an individual setting.

[image]

The values of the EditText are saved in external variables and updated upon any change. Upon click of the reset Button in the group view, I want to reset all individual settings contained in the EditTexts to default values. This works but of course the EditTexts views are not updated until the child views are redrawn. I want the views to all change immediately upon click of the reset button.

I have tried a myriad of things but keep running into issues. I can't seem to access the EditText views within the reset Button listener to programmatically set the text.

My Expandable List (abridged):

```
public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter
{
private String[] listGroups;
private String[][] listChilds;
private Activity context;
final EditText[] etIndividualLetterValues = new EditText[26];

public ExpandableListAdapter(Activity context, String[] listGroups, String[][] listChilds)
    {
    this.context = context;
    this.listGroups = listGroups;
    this.listChilds = listChilds;

@Override
public View getChildView(final int listGroupPosition, final int listChildPosition, boolean isLastChild,
                         View view, ViewGroup viewGroup)
    {
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    TextView tvListItemGeneral;

    tvListItemGeneral = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.TV_list_item_general);
    tvListItemGeneral.setText(getChild(listGroupPosition, listChildPosition).toString());

    etIndividualLetterValues[listChildPosition] = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.ET_list_item_settings_value);
    etIndividualLetterValues[listChildPosition].setText(String.format("%d", Settings.settingsCurrent[listGroupPosition][listChildPosition]));

    etIndividualLetterValues[listChildPosition].addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
        {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)
            {
            }
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
            {
            Settings.settingsCurrent[listGroupPosition][listChildPosition] = Integer.parseInt(s.toString());
            }
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
            {

            }
        }); 
    }

@Override
public View getGroupView(final int listGroupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup)
    {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if(view == null)
        {
        view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, viewGroup, false);
        }
    TextView tvListGroup = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.TV_list_group);
    Button buttonSettingsReset = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.B_settings_reset);
    buttonSettingsReset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
            {
            if(listGroupPosition == C.INDIVIDUAL_LETTER_VALUES)
                {
                for(int i=0; i<26; i++)
                    {
                    etIndividualLetterValues[i].setText(String.format("%d", Settings.settingsDefault[C.INDIVIDUAL_LETTER_VALUES][i]));
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    tvListGroup.setText(getGroup(listGroupPosition).toString());
    return view;
    }
```

The line of code:

```
etIndividualLetterValues[i].setText(String.format("%d", Settings.settingsDefault[C.INDIVIDUAL_LETTER_VALUES][i]));
```

gives a NPE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK after much searching (and rephrasing my searches!) I found out about the method notifyDataSetChanged();

So all I did was add a method to the Button click listener that called a method to reset settings and then called notifyDataSetChanged():

```
buttonSettingsReset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
        {
        if(listGroupPosition == C.INDIVIDUAL_LETTER_VALUES)
            {
            refresh(listGroupPosition);
            }
        }
    });

//...

public void refresh(int settingsID)
    {
    resetSettingsClick(context, settingsID);
    this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```